# How can I make objects spawn at random positions on the terrain?

Tags: unity, c#, terrain

I want to spawn some objects like trees etc. on my terrain randomly.

I use the script below:

```
public GameObject Tree;

public GameObject Stone;

public GameObject MetalOre;

private float xMinimum, xMaximum, zMinimum, zMaximum;

public int Tele;

public Vector3 yPos;

private void Start()
{
    GameObject terrainObj = GameObject.Find("Terrain");
    Terrain terrain = terrainObj.GetComponent<Terrain>();

    xMinimum = -3f;
    zMinimum = -43f;
    xMaximum = xMinimum + 62f;
    zMaximum = zMinimum + 40f;

    float xRand = Random.Range(xMinimum, xMaximum);
    float zRand = Random.Range(zMinimum, zMaximum);

    Vector3 yPos = new Vector3(xRand, 0, zRand);

    yPos.y = terrain.SampleHeight(yPos) + terrain.GetPosition().y;

    for (int i = 0; i < Tele; i++)
    {
        GameObject TreeObj = Instantiate(Tree, yPos, Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject StoneObj = Instantiate(Stone, yPos, Quaternion.identity);
        GameObject MetalOreObj = Instantiate(MetalOre, yPos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

The problem is that all of these objects spawn at one place, like this:

[image: Unity terrain with a tree and rock overlapping in the same spot]

I know why is that happening (that's because all of the game objects get the same position, I guess), but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Presumably you considered doing your calculation of a random position inside the loop, once before spawning each object? Puting it in a function you can just call to get a new position would help you avoid repetitive code. Where did you run into problems changing the code in this way?

Comment: @DMGregory that's a good idea, but I'm not really sure how could I do it.. could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: Note that this is a very common kind of refactoring, so if you're finding it unfamiliar, it might be a sign that you need to practice some more programming fundamentals - like working through some introductory coding tutorials, even if they're not about the kind of game you ultimately want to make. Making sure you have those fundamentals down pat will make your game go much smoother later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, refactor your random position-choosing code to a helper function:

```cs
// Packing X & Z together like this just means fewer arguments to type per call.
Vector3 GetRandomPointOnTerrain(Terrain terrain, Vector2 minXZ, Vector2 maxXZ) 
{
    var point = new Vector3(Random.Range(minXZ.x, maxXZ.x),
                            0,
                            Random.Range(minXZ.y, maxXZ.y));

    point.y = terrain.SampleHeight(point) + terrain.GetPosition().y;

    return point;
}
```

Then call this function once for each object to spawn:

```cs
private void Start()
{
    // If you have just one terrain, searching by type is faster
    // and more reliable than searching by name plus a GetComponent.
    var terrain = FindObjectOfType<Terrain>();

    var minXZ = new Vector2(-3f, -43f);
    var maxXZ = minXZ + new Vector2(62f, 40f);

    for (int i = 0; i < Tele; i++)
    {
        var TreeObj = Instantiate(
            Tree, 
            GetRandomPointOnTerrain(terrain, minXZ, maxXZ),
            Quaternion.identity);

        var StoneObj = Instantiate(
            Stone, 
            GetRandomPointOnTerrain(terrain, minXZ, maxXZ),
            Quaternion.identity);

        var MetalOreObj = Instantiate(
            MetalOre, 
            GetRandomPointOnTerrain(terrain, minXZ, maxXZ),
            Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Note that because each of these points is chosen independently, there's a chance that the same or very nearby positions will be chosen for two objects, leading to penetration. [Some existing Q&A goes into more detail about strategies to avoid that](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+overlap), so I won't cover it here.